# Allocate memory for a vector of pointers inside of a structure

Tags: c++

I have the following structure:

```
struct node{
  char name;
  vector<node*> children;

  void addChild(char name){
    node *newChild = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newChild->name = name;
    children.push_back(newChild);
  }
};
```

The code above compiles but crashes with a std::bad_alloc prompt whenever addChild is called for any node that was created using addChild.

It seems to me like i should somehow be allocating memory for the vector as well, but i am unsure about how i would go about doing that.

I am a "begginer" and know very little about memory allocation so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `malloc` and `free` in C++. Especially for objects that needs to have their constructor called, since `malloc` does *not* call the constructor.

In your case it means that the `std::vector` constructor will not be called, and you will have *undefined behavior* when you use the vector.

Use `new` and `delete` instead.

[Any good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have told you this.

Comment: yup. replacing `node *newChild = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` with `node *newChild = new node` made it work. Thank you!